# Clean Ubuntu Install with Nvidia stuck on login screen, login loop

Tags: nvidia, login, password, login-screen

I'm a new Ubuntu user trying a first install.  I've just built a PC and everything went smooth right up until the Ubuntu login screen.  I am prompted to type in my password, I do, and nothing happens.  It goes right back to the login screen.  If I type in a wrong password it informs me the password is incorrect.   When the password is correct nothing happens.

Thanks for any help you can provide.  This is my first PC build and attempt at any type of linux.

Comment: Do you have Nvidia graphics or something like that?

Comment: Yes there is a graphics card in there.  Take that out?

Comment: No, you might need to install the drivers. If it is Nvidia, press CTRL+ALT+F3, sign into the terminal with your username and then password when prompted. Then, run the following command: `sudo apt update; sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: You will need an internet connection but you should be able to set that up on the original login screen. To get back to your original login screen, I think it's either CTRL+ALT+F2 or  CTRL+ALT+F1 but it could be  CTRL+ALT+F7. If all else fails, you can always run the following command to restart the login screen automatically `sudo systemctl restart gdm`.

Comment: I got in!!  Thank you so much!!  Have a great day!!

Comment: Awesome. I posted that as an answer so you can mark that as the accepted solution if that's what solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Nvidia graphics, you might need to install the drivers.

**First**, you will need to set up an internet connection through the login screen before you begin.

**Next**, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and sign in with your username and password.

**Then**, run the following commands to install the drivers:

```
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

---

You should be able to get back to the original login screen using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> but it may be <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

If all else fails, you can automatically restart the login screen by running the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm
```